# c++ using too much cpu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, cpu

ok im creating a game but it uses too much cpu but it doesn't uses too much memory.  the cpu does increase and decrease. i have too many timers in my game, i kill the timer when i don't use it any more so that should cause a problem but what i think that causes the problem is there is too many messages in my message qeue. i have new laptop it is 5 months old and it has a high cpu. it uses about 40% of my cpu. is there way to reduce it because when it gets to 40% the game slows down. 
here is my code

```
// Xstrike.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Xstrike.h"
#include <vector>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
RECT *rect;
const UINT_PTR EVERYTHING_ID=0x1;
const UINT_PTR LBUTTONDOWN_ID=0x3;
const UINT_PTR TDENEMIE1_ID=0x4;
const UINT_PTR TAENEMIE1_ID=0x5;
const UINT_PTR PROTECTED_ID=0x6;
int conno=2;
int health=0;
int life=3;
int score=0;
int level=1;
int protect=0;
int cursor=0;
HCURSOR hCursor[3];

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

struct Enemies
{
    int cEnemie1;
    int dEnemie1;
    int aEnemie1;
    int sEnemie1;
    int pEnemie1;
    bool e1;
    time_t now;
    time_t tEnemie1;
    vector <POINT> vS1Enemie1;
    vector <POINT> vS2Enemie1;
};

vector <POINT> vRegularShots;
Enemies Enemie1;
VOID installising()
{
    Enemie1.cEnemie1=0;
    Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
    Enemie1.aEnemie1=0;
    Enemie1.sEnemie1=1;
    Enemie1.pEnemie1=550;
    Enemie1.e1=true;
    POINT pt;
    pt.x=0;
    pt.y=0;
    vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
}
VOID Paint(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    int lifePos=200;
    hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC memDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hMemMap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 225, 350);
    HBITMAP hOldMap=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemMap);
    Graphics draw(memDC);

    // Drawing
    Image bg(L"bg.jpg");
    draw.DrawImage(&bg, 0, 0);

    // if regular cursor
    if(cursor==0)
    {
        // Regular shots
        Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");
        long s=vRegularShots.size();

        // Draw shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
        { 
            draw.DrawImage(&shot, vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y);
        }

        // Update the shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
        { 
            vRegularShots[index].y--;
        }

        // Delete Shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
            {
                vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
            }
        }

        // Create Enemies
        if(Enemie1.dEnemie1==0)
        {
            if(Enemie1.cEnemie1<2)
            {
                if(Enemie1.aEnemie1==0)
                {
                    SetTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
                }
                Enemie1.aEnemie1=1;
                Enemie1.cEnemie1++;
            }
            else
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID);
            }
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
        }

        // Draw enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y);
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y);
        }

        // Update enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x++;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y++;
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x--;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y++;
        }

        // Delete enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x>225)
            {
                Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x<-21)
            {
                Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }

        // player hits
        if(Enemie1.pEnemie1==550)
        {
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
            for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++)
            {
                if(((pt.x+5)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.x+5)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17)&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17))||((pt.x+15)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+21)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+21)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+23)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+23)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+13)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+31)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+31)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+13)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||(pt.x>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&pt.x<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+21))||((pt.x+3)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+21)&&(pt.x+3)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+21)))
                {
                    health+=30;
                    Enemie1.pEnemie1=0;
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                }
            }
            for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++)
            {
                if(((pt.x+5)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.x+5)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17)&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17))||((pt.x+15)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+21)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+21)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+23)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+23)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+13)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+31)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+31)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+13)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||(pt.x>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&pt.x<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+21))||((pt.x+3)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+21)&&(pt.x+3)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+21)))
                {
                    health+=30;
                    Enemie1.pEnemie1=0;
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                }
            }
        }

        if(health>225)
        {
            cursor=1;
            SetTimer(hWnd, PROTECTED_ID, 1000, NULL);
            life--;
            health=0;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
        }

        // Hits
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++)
        {
            for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); indexs++)
            {
                if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
                {
                    Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
                    vRegularShots[index].y=-17;
                    score+=100;
                    // Stop enemie1 timer
                    if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
                    {
                        KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); indexs++)
            {
                if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
                {
                    Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
                    vRegularShots[index].y=-17;
                    score+=100;
                    // Stop enemie1 timer
                    if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
                    {
                        KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If protected
    if(cursor==1)
    {
        if(protect!=4)
        {
            // Regular shots
            Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");

            // Draw shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
            { 
                draw.DrawImage(&shot, vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y);
            }

            // Update the shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
            { 
                vRegularShots[index].y--;
            }

            // Delete Shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
            {
                if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
                {
                    vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
                }
            }
            // Delete Shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
            {
                vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
            }
        }

        // Create Enemies
        if(Enemie1.dEnemie1==0)
        {
            if(Enemie1.cEnemie1<2)
            {
                if(Enemie1.aEnemie1==0)
                {
                    SetTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
                }
                Enemie1.aEnemie1=1;
                Enemie1.cEnemie1++;
            }
            else
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID);
            }
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
        }

        // Draw enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y);
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y);
        }

        // Update enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x++;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y++;
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x--;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y++;
        }

        // Delete enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x>225)
            {
                Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            KillTimer(hWnd, PROTECTED_ID);
            cursor=0;
            protect=0;
        }
    }

    // Draw Lifes
    for(long index=0; index != life; index++)
    {
        Image lifes(L"lifes.png");
        draw.DrawImage(&lifes, lifePos, 275);
        lifePos-=30;
    }

    SolidBrush textColor(Color(255, 255, 54, 0));
    LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush(
    Point(1000, 20),
    Point(health, 20),
    Color(255, 255, 0, 0),     // opaque black 
    Color(0, 0, 0, 0));  // opaque red
    SolidBrush databrush(Color(0, 225, 0));

    draw.FillRectangle(&databrush, 0, 0, 225, 30);
    draw.FillRectangle(&linGrBrush, 0, 0, 225, 30);

    FontFamily courieNew(L"Courier New");
    Font font(&courieNew, 12, 0, UnitPixel);
    PointF pLevel(5.0f, 6.0f);
    PointF pScore(100.0f, 6.0f);
    WCHAR wLevel[11];
    WCHAR wScore[60];
    _swprintf(wLevel, L"Level : %d", level);
    _swprintf(wScore, L"Score : %d", score);
    draw.DrawString(wLevel, -1, &font, pLevel, &textColor);
    draw.DrawString(wScore, -1, &font, pScore, &textColor);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 225, 350, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    SelectObject(memDC, hOldMap);
    DeleteObject(hMemMap);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
}


int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Cursors
    hCursor[0]=LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR));
    hCursor[1]=LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PROTECTED));

    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_XSTRIKE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_XSTRIKE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR));
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 225, 350, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    POINT pt;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        installising();
        SetTimer(hWnd, EVERYTHING_ID, 1, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Paint(hdc, hWnd);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
        if(conno==1)
        {
            conno++;
        }
        else
        {
            pt.x+=18;
            conno--;
        }
        vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
        SetTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID, 350, NULL); 
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        KillTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case EVERYTHING_ID:
            if(Enemie1.e1==true)
            {
                Enemie1.now=time(NULL);
                Enemie1.tEnemie1=Enemie1.now+1;
                Enemie1.e1=false;
            }
            Enemie1.now=time(NULL);
            if(Enemie1.now==Enemie1.tEnemie1)
            {
                SetTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case LBUTTONDOWN_ID:
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
            if(conno==1)
            {
                if(cursor==0)
                {
                    conno++;
                }
                else if(cursor==1)
                {
                    pt.x+=2;
                    conno++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(cursor==0)
                {
                    pt.x+=18;
                }
                else if(cursor==1)
                {
                    pt.x+=15;
                }
                conno--;
            }
            vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
            break;
        case TDENEMIE1_ID:
            pt.y=5;
            pt.x=-21;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            pt.y=5;
            pt.x=219;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=0;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case TAENEMIE1_ID:
            if(Enemie1.pEnemie1!=550)
            {
                Enemie1.pEnemie1+=550;
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case PROTECTED_ID:
            protect++;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
         SetCursor(hCursor[cursor]);
         return 0;
         break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

any idea?

Comment: This is *way* too much code to base a question around.  The only meaningful suggestion is to either profile your code, or experiment by chopping bits out.

Comment: "any idea?" Run game through profiler.

Comment: Yes, a profiler to find bottlenecks.

Comment: im using visual c++ 2010 does it have it?

Comment: Instantiating images constantly inside tight loops, such as `Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");` seems like a very bad idea. Can't you just load these on startup and reuse them ?

Comment: i tried what you said so im but the images varabiles as golable varabiles but now the images don't show i don't get any error

Comment: @Ramiz: I would suggest getting to better know C++ in general before attempting to build games with it. (You might also want to invest in a good spell checker ... `Enemie` -> `Enemy`)

Comment: You know about functions don't you?

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: a question here is that how do you know that it is too much? Was there an expected usage that was specified/estimated?

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Suggest you add "profiler" also the list of tags against this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that you are constantly re-allocating and re-drawing everything instead simply moving the images around.  I can see the application frequently having to re-allocate and re-draw from scratch having a bottleneck on the system.

Comment: im redarwing it everytime something changes is there way to just move images around without redrawing it

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize a little the paint function.
For example the creation of the four bitmaps could be done in an initialization phase since it is always the same files you are loading.
Also, in all the for loops, you can make one call to the size function of your vector, store it in a temporary variable and use that variable in the for loop for the condition ( as long as the size of the vectors doesn't change in the for loops).

Comment: well i tried to set them as globle varabiles but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the profiler that comes with VS 2010 details of which are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/profiler/)

That may be your best bet on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say without knowing more about usage patterns of the thing. A good profiler will do wonders - I've had good luck on Windows with AQTime, although it's not free which may not suit you.

A few observations which may or may not be relevant:

- You are drawing using GDI+. It is not fast and may well not scale to what you need. If I wanted rendering of complex scenes, I'd find something else.
- I am suspicious about you calling InvalidateRect in your Paint function. Seems odd to me (doesn't painting *validate* the image?). Also, you are still repainting everything regardless, so what's the point?
- You are using erase() on a vector to erase multiple (possibly many) random entries. This has quadratic performance and should be avoided for large vectors.
- In one spot there's a pair of nested loops (loop over all 'shots' followed by loop over all 'enemies'); those look like they'll scale badly to large numbers of both.

But you **really** need to find a profiler; I'm just guessing here.

Comment: i was download the AQTIME profiler it need 200mb that is alot

Comment: All the AQT packages we have here are under 100MB download? I don't think you're going to find anything dramatically smaller.