# c++ high cpu usage

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, cpu-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ using too much cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561613/c-using-too-much-cpu)

my game uses over 50% of cpu.  i found way to reduce the cpu to be 40-50% but i can't find any other way to reduce it.  i tried to use Code analyst profiler but it doesn't give me any good information in my code where im using my cpu.
here is my code

```
// Xstrike.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Xstrike.h"
#include <vector>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
RECT *rect;
const UINT_PTR EVERYTHING_ID=0x1;
const UINT_PTR LBUTTONDOWN_ID=0x3;
const UINT_PTR TDENEMIE1_ID=0x4;
const UINT_PTR TAENEMIE1_ID=0x5;
const UINT_PTR PROTECTED_ID=0x6;
int conno=2;
int health=0;
int life=3;
int score=0;
int level=1;
int protect=0;
int cursor=0;
HCURSOR hCursor[3];

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

struct Enemies
{
    int cEnemie1;
    int dEnemie1;
    int aEnemie1;
    int sEnemie1;
    int pEnemie1;
    bool e1;
    time_t now;
    time_t tEnemie1;
    vector <POINT> vS1Enemie1;
    vector <POINT> vS2Enemie1;
};

vector <POINT> vRegularShots;
Enemies Enemie1;
VOID installising()
{
    Enemie1.cEnemie1=0;
    Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
    Enemie1.aEnemie1=0;
    Enemie1.sEnemie1=1;
    Enemie1.pEnemie1=550;
    Enemie1.e1=true;
    POINT pt;
    pt.x=0;
    pt.y=0;
    vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
}
VOID Paint(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    int lifePos=200;
    hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC memDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hMemMap=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 225, 350);
    HBITMAP hOldMap=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemMap);
    Graphics draw(memDC);

    // Images
    Image bg(L"bg.jpg");
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");
    Image iEnemie1(L"Enemie1.png");
    Image lifes(L"lifes.png");

    // Drawing
    draw.DrawImage(&bg, 0, 0);

    // if regular cursor
    if(cursor==0)
    {
        // Regular shots
        long s=vRegularShots.size();

        // Draw shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
        { 
            draw.DrawImage(&shot, vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y);
        }

        // Update the shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
        { 
            vRegularShots[index].y--;
        }

        // Delete Shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
            {
                vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
            }
        }

        // Create Enemies
        if(Enemie1.dEnemie1==0)
        {
            if(Enemie1.cEnemie1<2)
            {
                if(Enemie1.aEnemie1==0)
                {
                    SetTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
                }
                Enemie1.aEnemie1=1;
                Enemie1.cEnemie1++;
            }
            else
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID);
            }
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
        }

        // Draw enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y);
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y);
        }

        // Update enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x++;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y++;
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x--;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y++;
        }

        // Delete enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x>225)
            {
                Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x<-21)
            {
                Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }

        // player hits
        if(Enemie1.pEnemie1==550)
        {
            POINT pt;
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
            for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++)
            {
                if(((pt.x+5)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.x+5)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17)&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17))||((pt.x+15)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+21)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+21)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+23)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+23)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+13)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+31)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+31)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+13)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+17))||(pt.x>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+17)&&pt.x<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+21))||((pt.x+3)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y+21)&&(pt.x+3)<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x+21)))
                {
                    health+=30;
                    Enemie1.pEnemie1=0;
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                }
            }
            for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++)
            {
                if(((pt.x+5)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.x+5)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17)&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17))||((pt.x+15)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&pt.y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&pt.y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+21)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+21)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+23)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+23)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||((pt.x+13)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+31)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+31)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&(pt.x+13)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+17))||(pt.x>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+22)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+22)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+17)&&pt.x<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+21))||((pt.x+3)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x&&(pt.y+14)>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y&&(pt.y+14)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y+21)&&(pt.x+3)<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x+21)))
                {
                    health+=30;
                    Enemie1.pEnemie1=0;
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
                }
            }
        }

        if(health>225)
        {
            cursor=1;
            SetTimer(hWnd, PROTECTED_ID, 1000, NULL);
            life--;
            health=0;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
        }

        // Hits
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++)
        {
            for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); indexs++)
            {
                if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
                {
                    Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
                    vRegularShots[index].y=-17;
                    score+=100;
                    // Stop enemie1 timer
                    if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
                    {
                        KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); indexs++)
            {
                if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
                {
                    Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
                    vRegularShots[index].y=-17;
                    score+=100;
                    // Stop enemie1 timer
                    if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
                    {
                        KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // If protected
    if(cursor==1)
    {
        if(protect!=4)
        {
            // Regular shots

            // Draw shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
            { 
                draw.DrawImage(&shot, vRegularShots[index].x, vRegularShots[index].y);
            }

            // Update the shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); ++index) 
            { 
                vRegularShots[index].y--;
            }

            // Delete Shots
            for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
            {
                if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
                {
                    vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
                }
            }
            // Delete Shots
        for(long index=0; index < (long)vRegularShots.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(vRegularShots[index].y<-16)
            {
                vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
            }
        }

        // Create Enemies
        if(Enemie1.dEnemie1==0)
        {
            if(Enemie1.cEnemie1<2)
            {
                if(Enemie1.aEnemie1==0)
                {
                    SetTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
                }
                Enemie1.aEnemie1=1;
                Enemie1.cEnemie1++;
            }
            else
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID);
            }
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=1;
        }

        // Draw enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y);
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); ++index) 
        {
            draw.DrawImage(&iEnemie1, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x, Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y);
        }

        // Update enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x++;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].y++;
        }
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].x--;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[index].y++;
        }

        // Delete enemies
        for(long index=0; index < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size(); index++) 
        {
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[index].x>225)
            {
                Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+index);
            }

            // Stop enemie1 timer
            if(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size()==0&&Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size()==0)
            {
                KillTimer(hWnd, TAENEMIE1_ID);
            }
        }
        }
        else
        {
            KillTimer(hWnd, PROTECTED_ID);
            cursor=0;
            protect=0;
        }
    }

    // Draw Lifes
    for(long index=0; index != life; index++)
    {
        draw.DrawImage(&lifes, lifePos, 275);
        lifePos-=30;
    }

    SolidBrush textColor(Color(255, 255, 54, 0));
    LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush(
    Point(1000, 20),
    Point(health, 20),
    Color(255, 255, 0, 0),     // opaque black 
    Color(0, 0, 0, 0));  // opaque red
    SolidBrush databrush(Color(0, 225, 0));

    draw.FillRectangle(&databrush, 0, 0, 225, 30);
    draw.FillRectangle(&linGrBrush, 0, 0, 225, 30);

    FontFamily courieNew(L"Courier New");
    Font font(&courieNew, 12, 0, UnitPixel);
    PointF pLevel(5.0f, 6.0f);
    PointF pScore(100.0f, 6.0f);
    WCHAR wLevel[11];
    WCHAR wScore[60];
    _swprintf(wLevel, L"Level : %d", level);
    _swprintf(wScore, L"Score : %d", score);
    draw.DrawString(wLevel, -1, &font, pLevel, &textColor);
    draw.DrawString(wScore, -1, &font, pScore, &textColor);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 225, 350, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    SelectObject(memDC, hOldMap);
    DeleteObject(hMemMap);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
}


int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Cursors
    hCursor[0]=LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR));
    hCursor[1]=LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PROTECTED));

    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_XSTRIKE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_XSTRIKE));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR));
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_XSTRIKE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 225, 350, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    POINT pt;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        installising();
        SetTimer(hWnd, EVERYTHING_ID, 1, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        Paint(hdc, hWnd);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
        if(conno==1)
        {
            conno++;
        }
        else
        {
            pt.x+=18;
            conno--;
        }
        vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
        SetTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID, 350, NULL); 
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        KillTimer(hWnd, LBUTTONDOWN_ID);
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case EVERYTHING_ID:
            if(Enemie1.e1==true)
            {
                Enemie1.now=time(NULL);
                Enemie1.tEnemie1=Enemie1.now+1;
                Enemie1.e1=false;
            }
            Enemie1.now=time(NULL);
            if(Enemie1.now==Enemie1.tEnemie1)
            {
                SetTimer(hWnd, TDENEMIE1_ID, 550, NULL);
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case LBUTTONDOWN_ID:
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
            if(conno==1)
            {
                if(cursor==0)
                {
                    conno++;
                }
                else if(cursor==1)
                {
                    pt.x+=2;
                    conno++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(cursor==0)
                {
                    pt.x+=18;
                }
                else if(cursor==1)
                {
                    pt.x+=15;
                }
                conno--;
            }
            vRegularShots.push_back(pt);
            break;
        case TDENEMIE1_ID:
            pt.y=5;
            pt.x=-21;
            Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            pt.y=5;
            pt.x=219;
            Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.push_back(pt);
            Enemie1.dEnemie1=0;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case TAENEMIE1_ID:
            if(Enemie1.pEnemie1!=550)
            {
                Enemie1.pEnemie1+=550;
            }
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
            break;
        case PROTECTED_ID:
            protect++;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
         SetCursor(hCursor[cursor]);
         return 0;
         break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

if you know good profiler that is free, or any idea how to reduce my cpu usage.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561613/c-using-too-much-cpu by him.

Comment: really? i couldn't get answer over there okay?

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works makes it preferable that you post your questions only once, and if you don't get satisfying answers, try to edit your question to include the details required to post a better answer. People have commented on your question, giving you suggestions and telling you it's too much code at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about profiling Windows code, but your program is so small and simple (in absolute terms - it's a lot to read on stackoverflow), that you could easily instrument it manually.  I Googled up these functions:

```
LARGE_INTEGER from;
LARGE_INTEGER to;

QueryPerformanceCounter (&from);
// do stuff
QueryPerformanceCounter (&to);

LARGE_INTEGER elapsed = to - from;

LARGE_INTEGER hertz;
QueryPerformanceFrecuency (&hertz);
```

Use your understanding of where the program might spend time to refine your placement of timers, drilling down on the slow code.

Answer (score 0):

do your profiling yourself using QueryPerofmanceCounter,  Microsoft have an article on how to do exactly that here :-

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815668